# RefCell alternative that can be `Send`?

Tags: rust

I was designing a type that can be sent between threads or not, depending if it's an Owned type or not.

This code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub enum M<'a, T> {
    Owned(),
    Ref(Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [T]>>)
}

fn main() {
    let m: M<'static, u8> = M::Owned();
    std::thread::spawn(||{
        let m = m;
    });
}
```

gives

```
error[E0277]: `Rc<RefCell<&mut [_]>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:11:5
    |
11  |       std::thread::spawn(||{
    |  _____^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_-
    | |     |
    | |     `Rc<RefCell<&mut [_]>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
12  | |         let m = m;
13  | |     });
    | |_____- within this `[closure@src/main.rs:11:24: 13:6]`
```

I understand that this is not `Send` because `RefCell` is `!Send`. I think this is the only thing preventing `M` from being `Send`. Is there a `RefCell` alternative that is `Send`?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68241072/5987669 which was asked a couple minutes earlier?

Comment: You can share an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` as much as you want. However, having this struct seems like it will cause more problems than it is worth. That lifetime will likely cause you issues going forward. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0429ef270924698439df880514ebc607)

Comment: @Locke I only expect to `Send` the `'static` version of this struct. On every code that sends it to another thread, it already expects `M` to be `'static`. However I still want to support some cases where it holds a reference, so things can be done on the same thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that this is not Send because RefCell is !Send. I think this is the only thing preventing M from being Send.

Yes, this is correct.

> Is there a RefCell alternative that is Send?

Of course, at least two. If you just want the `&mut` in another thread, you can actually just send it:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum M<'a, T> {
    Owned(),
    Ref(&'a mut [T])
}

fn main() {
    let m: M<'static, u8> = M::Owned();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        println!("{:?}", m);
    }).join().unwrap();
}
```

But if you use the `Rc<RefCell<_>>` to e.g. make your `&mut` sharable, you can achieve the same thing in the context of multithreading with `Arc<Mutex<_>>`, as @Locke already mentioned:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum M<'a, T> {
    Owned(),
    Ref(Arc<Mutex<&'a mut [T]>>)
}

fn main() {
    let m: M<'static, u8> = M::Owned();
    let m2 = m.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        println!("{:?}", m2);
    }).join().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```